# Spring JavaMailSender How to set confidentiality for the message

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

We are Spring Java Mail to send emails from our web app.

If we want to set the message as "confidential" or "sensitive" . Is there any way to do
using Java Spring Mail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak specifically as to Spring, but these fields can be set by just including one of the following additional SMTP headers:

```
Sensitivity: company-confidential
Sensitivity: personal
Sensitivity: private
```

(Outlook doesn't provide for sending an email as "sensitive" - you probably meant "personal" or "private".  "company-confidential" maps to "confidential".)

Using regular JavaMail, this can be set using [`Part.setHeader`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/277476/which-mail-header-does-outlook-2003-use-to-indicate-the-confidentiality